# How to cluster 2 datasets in Google Maps API V3?

Tags: google-maps, clustering

I'd like to produce a map that shows thousands of Markers.
I'm using Markersclusterer to show all these markers.
Yesterday, I received another huge data set (completely different) and I'd like to see its markers with the ones that belong to the previous data set (using MarkerClusterer.
So, I can have different icons for those two data sets.
Can you help me do this?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Clustering using Google Maps API (v3)**

Grid-based Clustering

Distance-based Clustering

Viewport Marker Management

*"In this article, we've shown various advanced marker management techniques within the Maps API. No one technique is "right" or "wrong" so choose the technique that works best for you within your application"*

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/toomanymarkers.html

Comment: Hi I'm already using the MarkerClusterer for one of the dataSets. Now, I have a new dataSet (completely different) and like to display it along with the previous one. So, if for the previous one I have a cluster that has an icon “m1.png”   I’d like to have another icon for the same cluster size. I tried to use the MarkerClusterer for both datasets but could not have this duality.